# Ember Adapter Dynamic Path Using pathForType

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm extending an adapter:

```
import config from '../config/environment';
import Firebase from 'firebase';
import Ember from 'ember';
import ApplicationAdapter from './application';

export default ApplicationAdapter.extend({
  pathForType: function(type) {
    return "posts/" + this.get("session.auth.uid") + "/causeRecs";
  }
});
```

I would like the adapter to also be able to dynamically set the pathForType using a property of the record to be saved ( record_A ):

```
return "posts/" + this.get("session.auth.uid") + "/causeRecs/" + this.get("record_A.path");
```

How to gain access to the property of the record being saved (record_A)?

Comment: Why do you want to do that ?, Do you want to append `path` to url when is being saved or created?